# Finding all possible values of x and y with complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

The problem is$$\frac{x+iy}{x-iy} = -i$$ 
where $i$ is the imaginary number $\sqrt-1$. I know this is quite basic but I just do not know how to do this. My attempt thus far is:

multiplying the top and bottom of the LHS by the conjugate of $x-iy$, $x+iy$, we have $$\frac{(x+iy)^2}{(x-iy)(x+iy)} = -i$$
$$\frac{x^2+2ixy-y^2}{x^2+y^2} =-i$$
Now how do I go on from here to find x and y?

Comment: equate the real part of LHS to real part of RHS and imaginary part of LHS to imaginary part of RHS. Also, your denominator will be $x^2+y^2$ not $x^2-y^2$.

Comment: Couldn't you just multiply both sides by $x-iy$?

Comment: Oh yes I had that, I just copied it down wrongly. Let me correct it.

Comment: Yeah, but the question asks for how to proceed further from that step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By equating the real part of LHS to real part of RHS, you'll  get,

$\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} = 0 \Rightarrow x^2 = y^2$

By equating the imaginary part of LHS to imaginary part of RHS, you'll  get,

$\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2} = -1 \Rightarrow (x+y)^2 = 0 \Rightarrow x = -y$

Therefore, final answer will be $x = -y$.

Note that, $a+ib = c+id$ if and only if $a = c$ and $b=d$.

For alternative and better approach checkout the solution of @ET93.

Answer (score 5):

Move the denominator to the other side:

$x+iy=-ix-y$

$(i+1)x=-(i+1)y$

$x=-y$

Answer (score 0):

A very quick approach would be to use the e-power. Since $z=e^{i\theta}$, the equation becomes $\frac{e^{i\theta}}{e^{-i\theta}}=e^{-i\pi/2}$. Lefthand side becomes $e^{2i\theta}$ and setting exponents equal results in an easy equation with an answer $\theta=\frac{{-\pi}}{4}$ and $r$ free

Answer (score 0):

The equation says $z^*=iz$: mirroring about the $x$ axis is the same as rotating by $90°$. This means that $z$ is on a principal bissector.